# Canvas.LineTo method parameters?

Tags: javascript, canvas

So i'm passing array values to canvas.moveTo and canvas.LineTo functions but the line is not being rendered.When i simply enter values,it works quite well.

```
var arr2=[];
        for(var d in data){
            arr[d]=data[d];
            arr2[d]=(Math.round(arr[d]*100));
            console.log(arr2[d]);
        }


var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.beginPath(); 

    context.moveTo(arr2[0],arr2[1]);
    context.lineTo(arr2[2],arr2[3]);
    context.lineTo(arr2[4],arr2[5]);
    context.lineTo(arr2[6],arr2[7]);


    context.stroke();
```

Comment: And arr2 is...?

Comment: And array of integers.

Comment: Are you sure? Because when you enter values, it works quite well. Can you include the Array?

Comment: Why do you think it's not relevant? Have you checked the console for errors, btw?

Comment: There are no errors on the console log.

Comment: I'm printing the values from arr2 on the console log and they are being displayed fine.

Comment: I've added an "answer" showing that your code works just fine. And since you get no errors, the only thing that can be wrong is your "array of integers" that you don't want to show.

Comment: @Thomas I have added my array code.

Comment: It also works fine for me when i use a defined array like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just showing that your code works flawlessly, and the only thing that may be broken is your array of integers; wich you don't want to show, and insist that it looks "fine" when displayed in the console.

```js
var arr2 = [10, 10, 60, 10, 60, 60, 10, 60];
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.lineWidth = 10;
context.beginPath();

context.moveTo(arr2[0], arr2[1]);
context.lineTo(arr2[2], arr2[3]);
context.lineTo(arr2[4], arr2[5]);
context.lineTo(arr2[6], arr2[7]);

context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```